# How can I push to the top an element using slideUp?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XyHaD/2/) code:

#### HTML

```
<div class="box_meteo">
    <div class="box_meteo_pulsanti">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"
           class="box_meteo_pulsante" id="meteoButton1">Link</a>
    </div>

    <div class="meteo_content">
       Text
    </div>        
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.box_meteo
{
    width:600px;
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
}

.box_meteo_pulsanti
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}

a.box_meteo_pulsante
{
    float:left;
    color:#ffffff;    
}

#meteoButton1
{
    width:150px;
    height:24px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    color:red;
}

.meteo_content
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:300px;
    height:180px;
    display:none;
    background-color:#2c2c2c;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#meteoButton1').click(function() {
    if ($(".meteo_content").is(":hidden")) {
        $('.meteo_content').slideDown('slow', function() {
            return true;
        });
    } else {
        $('.meteo_content').slideUp('slow', function() {
            return true;
        });
    }
});
```

and I'd like, when I click on `Link`, to move also that link to the top, such as the link is "propped" on the div. So it must not be "fixed" to the bottom. 
In less words : "*moving the link to the top with the progression of the div's height*"

How can I do it? Hope the question is clear...

Comment: You want the link to be moved to the top, but also fixed to the bottom? I'm confused.

Comment: here is a present for you: http://jsfiddle.net/XyHaD/4/ :) (use slideToggle)

Comment: I want the link moving to the top with the progression of the div's height :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/SpWgy/).

You need to put the link and the content in the same container, then fix *that* to the bottom. When you animate the height of the `.content` with `.slideToggle()`, it will push up the `.toggler` link.

#### HTML

```
<div class="toggleBox">
    <a href="#" class="toggler">Link</a>
    <div class="content">
       Text
    </div>    
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('.toggleBox').each(function() {
    var box = $(this);
    box.find('a.toggler').click(function(e) {
        box.find(".content").slideToggle();

        return false;
        //or e.preventDefault(), depending on whether you want it to bubble
    });
});
```

#### CSS

```
.toggleBox
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 300px;
}

.toggleBox .toggler
{
    height: 24px;
    color: red;
    display: block;
}

.toggleBox .content
{
    height: 180px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: if you change the return fasle to preventDefault() you got my +1

Comment: @meo: Why? What's the difference?

Comment: return false stops the the propagation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false if you do something else maybe on some parent, where you need to get the callback, you will have problems when i used return false;

Comment: @meo: doesn't it depend on what the OP wants? I can't think of a situation where you'd want to bind an event to the parent and want it fired when the box is toggled. I've thrown in a comment mentioning that `.preventDefault` is an alternative.

Comment: you never know what you may want in the future. Its always good to build your stuff in a way its maintainable and easy to reuse. I can think of tons of situations where you want to do this... http://jsfiddle.net/XyHaD/5/ +you dont want your function to return false; why should it? Oh i clicked, everythin is fine but it returns false; did something go wrong?

Comment: Uhm...teorically using javascript:void(0) prevent default doesnt have any influences?!?!?

Comment: I mean : prevent default is influent with javascript:void(0);

Comment: @markzzz: If you use `javascript:void(0);` instead of `#`, then you don't need to `e.preventDefault()`, since there is no default to prevent. You can still optionally `return false`.

Comment: @Eric : Yeah I know, its what I mean :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XUncm/

Comment: That is great. I have been wanting to know how to do this as such. Great example.